# Is there any historical documentation about witches using windows for divination?

Tags: history, bible, magic, witchcraft, objects

Is there any historical documentation about witches using windows for divination?
I have seen some rabbinic scholars (like [Alshich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Alshich), [Albo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Albo), [Abarbanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Abarbanel), and [Saba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Saba)) ntrepret the Biblical passages concerning Sisersa's mother looking through a window (Judges 5:28) and Abimelekh looking through a window (Gen. 26:8) as referring to them divining by way of an enchanted window.

I have heard of divining via a "mirror on the wall" (ala Snow White, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Mirror_(Snow_White))), so I'm specifically looking for ancient sources or mentions of a similar practice using a window.